# Search and Insert multiple values selected in textbox into MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm doing something in PHP which displays all the data let's say animals table for easier understanding. Now I have a kingdom table where all of the animals that falls into their respective kingdoms. Now In my Page I displayed two tables: Those animals who falls into the Kingdom I logged in (given Animalia) and Those who dont.

In those animals who are not part of the Kingdom Animalia there is a checkbox besided each names where I can select one or more names. Now I have an add button to serve as the trigger to add those animals I selected to be assigned in Kingdom Animalia.

Now it becomes a zoology class, sorry for the sample but I think I can explain in much better this way.

To add, as much as possible I wanted my code to be limited in using javascript and php codes only since I'm not used in working with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of the question...in the not assigned table i'm presuming that you have a checkbox besides a user name who is not assigned(linked) to our current user..
Now, add a button next to that new user's name to be assigned to our user.
Trigger the onclick event on that button using jquery on just javascript.

```
function adduser(){
    var elems = $(".Checkbox");
    for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
    {   
        if(elems[i].checked){
            var userId = elems[i].id;
            $("#dummy").load("adduser.php?user_id="+userId,function(){
                $("#"+userId).parent().remove();
            });
        }
    }
    $("#dummy").html("succesfully Added selectd users to your account.");
}
```

In the file adduser.php write the code for adding a user to the current user.

Comment: Yes that's right sorry I can't explain it naturally. Anyway, the thing is that every username must have a checkbox beside them wherein I can select all of the username I wanted to add for the current user after I click the Add button. Making the Add button the trigger in adding all of those usernames into the current user in 1 click. Also if possible I want to limit my code into javascript and php codes only.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand....

Post a checkbox with each of your table records along with your form

```
<!--non assigned table-->
<table id="non-table">
<tr id="nonassignedid">
 <?php foreach($nonassigneddata as $data){ ?>
<td>....</td>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
</table>

<!--assigned table-->
<table>
<tr id="assignedid">
    foreach($yourresults as $result){

    <td>...</td>

    <?php
    $check = someFunctionToCheckAssigned($result,$youruserId);
    if($check){
    $checked = "checked='checked'";
    }else{
    $checked = "";
    }

     ?>
    <td><input type="checkbox" userid="<?php echo $userid; ?>" assigningproperyid="<?php echo $assignid; ?>" name="both" class="updateuser" <?php echo $checked ?> /></td>
    }
</tr>
</table>
```

Using Jquery Ajax method

```
$(".updateuser").click(function(){
var userid = $(this).attr('userid);
var propertyid = $(this).attr('assigningproperyid'); //what ever thing you want to assign
$.ajax({
  url: 'updateuser.php,
 type : "POST",
data : {'userid':userid ,'propid':propertyid },
  success: function( data ) { //return the data as assigned element id

            $('#non-table #data).remove(); //removing that tr from non -assinged

    }
  }
});
})
```

Comment: Yeah, and from what I can see from all of your reactions is that I don't deliver my question in a manner that is readable. Haha! Anyway, thanks for your answer. Will update my question now.